# Hide toolbar on listview scroll, android?

Tags: android-listview, scroll, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Just like new google guidelines I want to hide actionbar on listview scroll.
I have succeeded in implementing the same but if I scroll slowly the actionbar flickers. How can provide smooth animation on its show and hide.

This is my code

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLast;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mLast < firstVisibleItem) {
                if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                }
            }
            if (mLast > firstVisibleItem) {
                if (!getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                }
            }
            mLast = firstVisibleItem;
        }
    });
```

I have even tried putting these value for listview

```
 android:clipToPadding="false"
```

But it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By your code toolbar is hiding but it is not showing back again. Please help me i want to implement the same.

Comment: There is 3rd party library available. You can use that https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: I think the library is for RecyclerView and i am using ListView

Comment: I am so sorry I gave you the wrong link in hurry. Have a look at this one. This suits your need https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/README.md